# save data while destroying and recreating activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I've settings(called from `onCreateOptionMenu`) from my `Activity` which uses to update the UI on current `Activity`.

Starting Preferences on updating Preferences, Calling Activity needs to update UI on Preference basis.

Snippet how Preference called:-

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, PrefsSecondaryActivity.class);
in.putExtra("caller", "sx");
startActivityForResult(in, SECSETTINGS);
```

Catch to get the UI updates

```
if (requestCode == SECSETTINGS) {
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
}
```

I used to Re-Create that activity with the above snippet. Inside of `onCreate()` of `Activity`. I checked the Preference Name-value Pair and update the UI which workd perfectly fine.

#### *How to store the values which are inside that activity while destroying and recreating activity?*

As I'm Destroying and Recreating activity which renders whole new Activity with no values inside of  it.

I tried to set `onSavedInstanceState()` while calling Preferences and `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called in catch the `onActivityResult()`

Settings values in Preferences makes good change of SLOC. So it's not preferrable way right now.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: I don't get it.  Store the values in onPause() and reload in onCreate().  Please edit your question to make the problem you are having more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do that (I have some static variables declared in my Activity):

```
@Override
protected final void onRestoreInstanceState(final Bundle inState)
{
    // Restore the saved variables.
    isChartShown = inState.getBoolean("chart", false);
    qIndex = inState.getInt("index");
    scores = inState.getIntArray("scores");
}
@Override
protected final void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
{
    // Save the variables.
    outState.putBoolean("chart", isChartShown);
    outState.putInt("index", qIndex);
    outState.putIntArray("scores", scores);
}
```

This code works for me. I use it for saving some state variables used to maintain the values upon rotation.

**[EDIT]**

Otherwise, **if you force the app finishing**, then you'd go for **Sharedpreferences**:
just save your values before finishing and reload them in onCreate.

Comment: I've tried these but as I'm forcing to `finish()` the application it re-creates without saved Bundle in it.

Comment: Tht's my final way to go. But I need something which can do else then Preferences

Comment: A database? a CSV (or XML) file? Yes, but... wouldn't that be an overkill?